# Dash(Python) - can't update Slider's values based on input from another Slider

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I've started learning Dash(after using R-Shiny for ~3months). During which I've tried to make an app, which will have two `Slider`s, one of whose values(`min`, `max`, `step`) are fixed and values of the other `Slider` will be updated based on the input from first `Slider`. And I couldn't update values of second `Slider`.
Here's what I've done and tried:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as dash_html
import dash_core_components as dash_core
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from flask import Flask

# initiate the dash app with Flask server
app = Dash(__name__, server=Flask(__name__))


# code the ui now
app.layout = dash_html.Div(children=[
    dash_core.Slider(id="first_slider",
                     min=10, max=110, value=10, step=10,
                     marks={i : '{}'.format(i) for i in range(10,110,10)},
                     # marks={i : 'Level {}'.format(i) for i in range(10,110,10)}
                     ),
    dash_html.Hr(), dash_html.Hr(),

    # second slider
    dash_core.Slider(id="second_slider"),
    # # dash_html.Hr(),

    # print values from both sliders
    dash_html.Div(id="display_selected_values"),
    ])


# take the input from first and update second slider
@app.callback(Output(component_id='second_slider', component_property=['min','max']),
                                           # component_property='children'),
                                           # component_property='value'),
              [Input(component_id='first_slider', component_property='value')])
def print_the_value_from_slider(value_from_slider):
    # update the values of second slider. ex: if input is 10, second slider will have 11 to 20
    # return value_from_slider
    return list((value_from_slider+1, value_from_slider+1+10))

# @app.callback(Output(component_id="second_slider", component_property='options'),
#               [Input(component_id='second_slider', component_property='value')])
# def fill_second_slider(value_from_first_slider):
#     return range(value_from_first_slider+1, value_from_first_slider+1+10, 1)


# @app.callback(Output('display_selected_values', 'children'),
#               [Input('first_slider', 'value'),
#                Input('second_slider', 'value')])
# def set_display_children(first_input, second_input):
#     return '{} from {}s range'.format(second_input, first_input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and the error is:

```
dash.exceptions.NonExistentPropException: 
Attempting to assign a callback with
the property "['min', 'max']" but the component
"second_slider" doesn't have "['min', 'max']" as a property.

Here are the available properties in "second_slider":
['id', 'marks', 'value', 'className', 'disabled', 'dots', 'included', 'min', 'max', 'tooltip', 'step', 'vertical', 'updatemode', 'loading_state']
```

But, `Slider` does have `min` and `max` properties and they are listed in error too. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. But, the second slider is not getting updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider does have the `min` and `max` props, but you are trying to set a single prop `[min, max]` which does not exist. You need two outputs on your callback, one to each prop.

```py
@app.callback([Output(component_id='second_slider', component_property='min'),
               Output(component_id='second_slider', component_property='max')]
              [Input(component_id='first_slider', component_property='value')])
```

That should work.

Comment: Also, how do i update `marks` of second slider now? Do I now have to write one more callback function? and how do i do that?

Comment: You can add another `Output` to the list in the callback, and add another value to the list you return at the end of the callback function. You could add a separate callback function if you want, but I think handling it all in the same function is probably best here.

Comment: will you please be able to answer my another question on dash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076801/dashpython-centering-an-app-messes-up-datepickersingle-and-radioitems